# SSRS: Failure Sending Mail

Tags: reporting-services

For the past couple of weeks, our SSRS reports are randomly failing.  They will also fail when I try to manually run them in SSRS.  Our IT department cannot seem to figure out what is causing it.  This wasn't happening about a month or so ago and we have been using SSRS for over a year now to send reports to different departments.  The reports run fine in SSMS (most are 3 seconds or less) and they run fine in Visual Studio.  I have also changed timing on the reports to see if that would correct it so they would run when the server isn't running any other jobs.  Below are the messages from the log files.  Any ideas what I need to tell my IT department to fix?

> 2022-01-10 10:08:22.5759|ERROR|17|Unhandled error in the Web API.
> Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying
> content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException --->
> System.Net.HttpListenerException: The I/O operation has been aborted
> because of either a thread exit or an application request    at
> System.Net.HttpResponseStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> 2022-01-10 10:08:22.5759|INFO|17|NT Service\SQLServerReportingServices
> XXX.X.X.X: GET /api/v1.0/ManagementState - 0:00:00.0306071 Connection
> dropped| RequestID = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

I changed the above to X's that had the id or ip address.

Comment: You should probably post this on the Server Fault pages as it's not strictly a programming issue. `Connection dropped` would suggest an IT related issue. https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Ok will do.  Thanks!